# cv2.imwrite function not running properly

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

The `enhance_image()` function should write the edited photo to a folder. But it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even return an error in the command line so I'm having a hard time finding where I went wrong.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageEnhance
import tkinter.filedialog
import os, os.path
import cv2


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")

frame = tkinter.Frame(root, bg='gray')
frame.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

# Prompt a user to select an image by opening file explorer
def select_image():
    global myFiles, fileBrowse

    root.fileBrowse = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()
    fileLabel = Label(frame, text=root.fileBrowse, bg='gray', fg='white').pack()
    
# Enhance image
def enhance_image():
    
    imagein = cv2.imread(root.fileBrowse)
    ImageEnhance.Color(Image.open(root.fileBrowse)).enhance(0.5)
    imagein = Image.fromarray(imagein)
    imagein = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagein)

    # Make a folder then save the enhanced image there
    if not os.path.exists('cc_folder'):
        os.makedirs('cc_folder')
        path = 'cc_folder'
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, imagein))

appTitle = Label(root, text="AutoCC", font=("Colombo", 20, 'bold')).pack()
browseBtn = Button(frame, text="Browse Files", command=select_image)
browseBtn.pack(padx=0.2, pady=0)
enhanceBtn = Button(frame, text="Start", command=enhance_image).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If `cc_folder` does not exist, I get `TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'PhotoImage'` on the line `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, imagein))`.  If `cc_folder` exists, `cv2.imwrite(...)` will not be executed.

Comment: Or you could use `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename` to get the path of save. You should probably change the indentation levels.

Comment: @acw1668 Did the 'os.makedirs' didn't work for you? Python made one for me so I know it should write there at least.

Comment: Yes I know the `os.makedirs()` works. But do you understand what I mean?  When `cc_folder` does not exist, the folder will be created and I get the error when executing `cv2.imwrite(...)`.  After the `cc_folder` is created and `enhance_image()` is executed again, `cv2.imwrite(...)` will not be executed because `if not os.path.exists('cc_folder')` will be evaluated as False.

Comment: Well the problem with `join()` could be that you are trying to join a relative path. Try using absolute path.

Comment: The issue is that `imagein` (an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`) is used in `os.path.join(path, imagein)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Yeah, I got the error now. Is there a way to use `imagein` without having the error?

Comment: Actually you don't need `imagein` at all, just `root.fileBrowse` is enough.  Also you don't need to use `cv2` module to read and write the image, use `PIL.Image` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have used `imagein`, an instance of `ImageTk.PhotoImage()`, in `os.path.join(path, imagein)`.

Actually you don't need `imagein` at all, simply use `root.fileBrowse` is enough.  Also you can use `PIL.Image` to read and write image instead of using `cv2` module.

Below is a modified `enchance_image()`:

```py
def enhance_image():
    ### make sure `root.fileBrowse` is set
    image = ImageEnhance.Color(Image.open(root.fileBrowse)).enhance(0.5)
    path = "cc_folder"
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    fname = os.path.basename(root.fileBrowse)
    image.save(os.path.join(path, fname))
```